# Как используя keyboard ставить медиа на паузу и обратно?

Tags: python, python-keyboard

По типу:

```
import keyboard
keyboard.send("next track")
```

Comment: ничего не понятно, добавьте подробностей, каких только сможете

Comment: Нужна копия "Fn+F7", но с поддержкой ПК и ноутов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, никак, но можете использовать `pyautogui` (`pip install pyautogui`). В [документации](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) в самом низу можно найти список клавиш, для эмуляции, в том числе нужные вам ("playpause", "prevtrack", "nexttrack") и другие

Вот пример испльзования `pyautogui`

```
import pyautogui # Добавляем pyautogui

pyautogui.press("playpause") # Нажимаем кнопку паузы/воспроизведения
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто воспользуйтесь методом `send`.

```
keyboard.send('space')
```

Пробел может работать как пауза и пуск в активном окне плеера.

Что касается кнопки pause, можно посмотреть ответ на этот [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69488464/how-to-press-pause-key-in-python)

Comment: Жаль, но ни один вариант мне не подходит. Нужна полная копия "Fn+F7", но для всех устройств ПК/Ноут